# MySql tricky conditional in joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, where-clause

The first table has several fields but "PersonId" is the only one of interest.
The second table has "PersEmId" and "PersEmGr".

The mysql is:

```
   select  a.PersonId, b.PersEmId, b.PersEmGR
       from PersonRepDb a left join PersEm b 
       on a.PersonId = b.PersEmId
    (conditions to be figured out)
```

with no conditions the output is:

```
1   ABBOT.LE00  ABBOT.LE00  betty  
2   ABBOT.LE00  ABBOT.LE00  flutes  
3   ACKERBRO00
```

so we see ABBOT.LE is in two groups 'betty' and 'flutes', whereas ACKERBR000 is in no groups.

If the condition is:  where PersEmGr = 'flutes' the query returns only ABBOT.LE00, which  is correct.

However, I want to know who is NOT in 'flutes'.  If the condition is

```
where PersEmGr != 'flutes' OR PersEmGr  IS NULL
```

the query returns

```
1   ABBOT.LE00  ABBOT.LE00  betty <br>
2   ACKERBRO00
```

ABBOT.LE00 shows up here because although he is in 'flutes', he is also in 'betty' which fills the != 'flutes' part of the condition.

Can anyone suggest a way to write the condition so that the query picks up everyone who is not in flutes, whether they are in another group or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the condition in the `ON` clause.

```
select  a.PersonId, b.PersEmId, b.PersEmGR
from PersonRepDb a 
left join PersEm b on a.PersonId = b.PersEmId AND b.PersEmGR = 'flutes'
WHERE b.PersEmId IS NULL
```

Comment: I love it.  Never would have thought of this.